# Recommendation for personal database (Bento replacement) for iOS and OS X

Tags: osx, database, ios, csv

Looking for a personal database recommendation for iOS and OS X – basically a replacement for [Bento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento_(database)). It needs to be able to have cloud sync, so I can do work on multiple devices.

Two options seem to be:

- Tap Forms
- Ninox

There is also a cross-platform and open source Symphytum, but it does not work for iOS.

**What is missing:** The main feature I am looking for that I haven't found is to have flatfile ([CSV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) storage as well. This would make it very useful if it is synced to the cloud, then can be parsed via JSON/HTML and displayed from the browser.

Comment: [This article in MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2066030/personal-database-roundup-bento-is-dead-long-live-bento.html) discusses alternatives to the killed Bento. You listed two of their four considered products.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details – and then [edit] your question and have it including your requirements etc. This will improve your chances for good answers significantly :)

Answer (score 0):

Several years too late but.... Since Bento has ground to a such a sluggish pace under Mojave, I've been dual booting back and forth with High Sierra for the last few months.

I'd looked for replacements before and found several of the pretenders to be lack certain things that fitted the way I, and Bento, worked.

I cracked and bought Tap Forms 5 today.

[Tap Forms](https://www.tapforms.com/) has it all. It's the perfect replacement. I'm only a few hours into using it and am already very happy with my purchase.

If anyone else out there has a need for a database app for the mac and is hesitant about splashing the cash, the Tapforms website has a 10 day trial to allow you to check it out before you buy either direct from them or through the app store